# Is NSOperationQueue mainQueue serial or concurrent?

Tags: ios, grand-central-dispatch, nsoperationqueue

Since NSOperation queue is built on top of GCD, is [NSOperationQueue mainQueue] a serial queue or concurrent queue?

Answer (score 2):

Serial. Everything going through the main queue is executed on the main thread. As there's only one of those, the rest of the queue has to wait for it to be open.

Comment: It's also worth noting that this remains true even if the `NSOperation` subclass returns `YES` for `-isConcurrent`. It you enqueue such an operation on `[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]`, no other `NSOperation`s enqueued to `[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]` will begin until the first one finishes.